# SQL interview question: select, join, grouping

Tags: sql

At the interview got question:
What products clients bought before first order of brand "Brand 1". Select top 5 by orders.

Tables:

Items:

```
RezonItemID;BrandName
5555613;Brand 1
2315946;Brand 2
9132648;Brand 3
3125847;Brand 1
3126548;Brand 5
```

Orders:

```
ClientID;ClientOrderID;RezonItemID;FactMoment
00611847;4562145;5555613;2021-01-09
00798451;7987465;1321321;2021-08-10
00914751;3154844;9132648;2021-07-01
00975418;9797451;1312125;2021-09-09
00978461;9413235;9754512;2021-10-29
```

My decision:

```
WITH first_order AS (
SELECT ClientID, MIN(FactMoment) as o_date
FROM orders
JOIN items
USING(RezonItemID)
WHERE BrandName = 'Brand 1'
GROUP BY ClientID
)

SELECT RezonItemID, COUNT(*) AS n_orders
FROM orders
JOIN items
USING(RezonItemID)
JOIN first_order
USING(ClientID)
WHERE FactMoment < o_date
GROUP BY RezonItemID
ORDER BY n_orders DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Is it possible to solve this by window functions? Maybe there is better decision?

Answer (score 1):

Given the following tables

```sql
1  RezonItemID;BrandName 
2  5555613;Brand 1
3  2315946;Brand 2
4  9132648;Brand 3
5  3125847;Brand 1
6  3126548;Brand 5
7  
8  ClientID;ClientOrderID;RezonItemID;FactMoment
9  00611847;4562145;5555613;2021-01-09
10 00798451;7987465;1321321;2021-08-10
11 00914751;3154844;9132648;2021-07-01
12 00975418;9797451;1312125;2021-09-09
13 00978461;9413235;9754512;2021-10-29
```

It seems that if the question is "Which products did the clients buy before the first order for an item of Brand 1," a sql query may not be necessary. Assuming that FactMoment is a timestamp for the order, we can see that the first order has the earliest date (01/09/21) and has a "RezonItemID" `5555613`. That item has the brand "Brand 1".

So the answer would be that no items were purchased before the first purchase of an item with `BrandName = 'Brand 1'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a puzzling question, the sample test data is not particularly useful since it yields no testable results so is pretty much useless.

If you want to use `window functions` then that's certainly possible.

The following successfully yields *no rows* and should work, but without proper test data it's hard to actually be sure!

Note `using()` is not supported by some databases, *ansi* join syntax is preferred.

```
select top(5) BrandName from (
    select o.ClientID, i.BrandName, o.FactMoment,
        Min(case when i.BrandName='Brand 1' then FactMoment end) over() earliest, 
        Count(*) over(partition by ClientID) qty
    from Orders o left join Items i on i.RezonItemID=o.RezonItemID
)o
where FactMoment<earliest
order by qty desc
```